# Why does sp_executesql fail in remote procedure but not when run on remote server directly?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a server A, which has a stored procedure that, among other things, has a remote call to another stored procedure, in server B.

B is a linked server in A, and I can successfully run any stored procedure in B from A.

There is just one stored procedure which fails to be executed in B from A. I have the error when calling the line

> EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER PROCEDURE ...'

The strange thing is, if I'm on server B, and I run the line manually, it executes it with no issue, and the stored procedure in B is successfully altered.

Why am I getting an issue when I do this:

- EXEC A.dbo.ProcedureA, which inside it calls:
- EXEC B.dbo.ProcedureB, which includes the line:
- EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER PROCEDURE ...' (which fails)

But no issue when I do EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER PROCEDURE ...' directly on B?

The error I'm getting says a subquery returned more than 1 row, but then again, this seems to be not an issue with the contents of the "ALTER PROCEDURE" statement, as I thought, since I can run it fine if I run it directly.

**PROCEDURE IN B**

In my console, I see all PRINT statement results except for the last one, "test > 2"

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[xsp_developer_tool__set_object_softvalmacen_dev_135]
    @NombreObjeto VARCHAR(100),
    @DefinicionObjeto BIGINT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT 'A'
    PRINT @NombreObjeto

    DECLARE @TextoDefinicion NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT TOP 1 Definicion FROM [172.16.126.90,53341].Newsoftv.dbo.VersionesObjetosBasesDeDatos WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Id = @DefinicionObjeto)
    SELECT Original = @TextoDefinicion
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ListaObjetosLocales') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #ListaObjetosLocales
    END
    CREATE TABLE #ListaObjetosLocales (
        id BIGINT,
        name VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    PRINT 'B'

    INSERT INTO #ListaObjetosLocales
    SELECT [id], [name] FROM sysobjects WHERE type IN (
            'P',  -- Stored Procedure
            'TR', -- Trigger
            'V',  -- View
            'FN', -- Scalar Function
            'TF' -- Table Functioin
            )
    PRINT 'C'
    DECLARE @ExistsLocally BIT
    IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM #ListaObjetosLocales WHERE name = @NombreObjeto) BEGIN
        SET @ExistsLocally = 1
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SET @ExistsLocally = 0
    END
    PRINT 'D'
    IF @ExistsLocally = 1 BEGIN
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE  PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE  PROC', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE PROC', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE  FUNCTION', 'ALTER FUNCTION')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE FUNCTION', 'ALTER FUNCTION')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE  VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE VIEW', 'ALTER VIEW')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE  TRIGGER', 'ALTER TRIGGER')
        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, 'CREATE TRIGGER', 'ALTER TRIGGER')
    END
    PRINT 'E'
    DECLARE @IndexEquivalencias BIGINT = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [172.16.126.135].Newsoftv.dbo.EquivalenciasLinkedServers ORDER BY Id)
    DECLARE @MaxIndexEquivalencias BIGINT = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [172.16.126.135].Newsoftv.dbo.EquivalenciasLinkedServers ORDER BY Id DESC)
    WHILE (@IndexEquivalencias <= @MaxIndexEquivalencias) BEGIN
        PRINT 'F'
        DECLARE @OriginText VARCHAR(50), @DestinationText VARCHAR(50)
        SELECT TOP 1 @OriginText = Origin, @DestinationText = Destination FROM [172.16.126.135].Newsoftv.dbo.EquivalenciasLinkedServers WHERE Id = @IndexEquivalencias

        SET @TextoDefinicion = REPLACE(@TextoDefinicion, @OriginText, @DestinationText)
        SET @IndexEquivalencias = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [172.16.126.135].Newsoftv.dbo.EquivalenciasLinkedServers WHERE Id > @IndexEquivalencias ORDER BY Id)
        PRINT 'G'
    END
    PRINT 'H'
    SELECT Final = @TextoDefinicion
    PRINT 'test > 1'
    EXEC sp_executesql N'ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[catdistribuidor_alta]
      @Nombre varchar(250),
      @RFC varchar(250),
      @CalleNumero varchar(1500),
      @Colonia varchar(70),
      @CodigoPostal varchar(5),
      @Ciudad varchar(70),
      @Pais varchar(70),
      @Lada1 varchar(3),
      @Telefono1 varchar(12),
      @Lada2 varchar(3),
      @Telefono2 varchar(12),
      @Email varchar(250),
      @NombreContacto varchar(250),
      @iddistribuidor int,
      @error    varchar(250) output,
      @ImportePagare money=0 ,
      @contingencia BIT = 0,
      @estados BIT = 0
as
begin
    begin try
        PRINT ''ASDF''
        PRINT ''QWERTY''

        declare @lexiste bit;
        declare @eExisteDis uniqueidentifier;
        declare @eNombre varchar(250);
        declare @NewVal uniqueidentifier;
        declare @NewDir uniqueidentifier;
        set @lexiste=0;

        select @lexiste=1, @eExisteDis=catDistribuidorClave from relcatDistribuidor
        where iddistribuidor=@iddistribuidor;
        if @lexiste is null set @lexiste=0

        if @lexiste=0 begin

            set @NewVal=newid();
            set @NewDir=newid();

            insert into domicilio(domicilioclave,CalleNumero,Colonia,CodigoPostal,Ciudad,Pais)
            values(@NewDir,@CalleNumero,@Colonia,@CodigoPostal,@Ciudad,@Pais);

            insert into catdistribuidor(catDistribuidorClave,Nombre,RFC,Lada1,Telefono1,Lada2,
                Telefono2,Email,NombreContacto,Activo,ImportePagare,domicilioclave,IdDistribuidor, Contingencia, Estados)
            values (@NewVal,@Nombre,@RFC,@Lada1,@Telefono1,@Lada2,@Telefono2,@Email,@NombreContacto,
                1,@ImportePagare,@NewDir,@iddistribuidor , @contingencia, @estados);

            insert into relcatDistribuidor(catDistribuidorClave,iddistribuidor)
            values (@NewVal,@iddistribuidor);

            set @error='''';
            return;
        end
        else begin
            select @eNombre=Nombre from catdistribuidor
            where @eExisteDis=catDistribuidorClave;
            set @error=''el distribuidor ya existe con el nombre ''+SUBSTRING (@eNombre,1,30);
            return;
        end
    end try
    begin catch
        set @error=ERROR_MESSAGE();
        return;
    end catch
end'
    PRINT 'test > 2'
    EXEC sp_executesql @TextoDefinicion
    PRINT 'I'
END
go
```

Comment: Without seeing the code we can't say for sure, but it's probably a subquery which could return multiple results, but is indeterminate. Please show relevant code

Comment: Not fully understanding where your issue is as clearly the error is the result of executing a query so what makes you think it's the *alter procedure* statement? It must be something you're not sharing.

Comment: Have you confirmed the linked server was assigned credentials with appropriate privileges to execute the statement on the linked server?

Comment: I've added PRINT statements right before and after that "EXEC sp_executesql" statement, and I only get the PRINT right before, that's how I pinpointed the issue to that line.

Comment: Add the complete code to your question. Certainly executing a cross-server query to execute a proc that contains an sp_executesql that alters another proc works in basic testing.

Comment: I added the procedure in B which is failing.

Comment: My nose smells a poorly implemented DDL trigger on the remote server. Do you have one? There are other side issues/poor practices here: use of `NOLOCK` which is just going to give you incorrect results. Use of `sysobjects` which is deprecate, use `sys.objects` instead. Use of a fixed IP address for a remote server. A `WHILE` loop for unclear reasons. Poor formatting and lack of whitespace. Use of `money` data type which has rounding issues, you should use `decimal` instead. Above all: a T-SQL script to do something as complex as this, which version control and deployment tools should be doing